# Lines are not drawn with PDFSharp on specific machines

Tags: .net, pdfsharp

I have weird problem. A generate a pdf file from a .net desktop app with PDFSharp 1.50.5147 and on some specific machines, the lines are not shown. All the other data, text is shown, but not a single linge. I have in pdf, multiples types of lines, different thickness, regular and dotted line. No lines is shown on these machines, only the text. The app generate the pdf on all other machines very well.

What should I look for? I reinstalled .Net Framework 4.7.2. replace de PdfSharp dll..

Any idea is appreciated!

The code:

```
Dim fo As XPdfFontOptions = New XPdfFontOptions(PdfFontEncoding.Unicode, PdfFontEmbedding.Always)
    Dim PrintFont14B As XFont = New XFont("Arial Narrow", 14, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, fo)
    Dim BrushBlack As XBrush = XBrushes.Black
    Dim BrushGrey As XBrush = XBrushes.Gray
    Dim BrushRed As XBrush = XBrushes.Red
    Dim BrushWhite As XBrush = XBrushes.White
    Dim pen As New PdfSharp.Drawing.XPen(XColor.FromName("black"))
    Dim penTabel As New PdfSharp.Drawing.XPen(XColor.FromName("black"))
    Dim penDespartitor As New PdfSharp.Drawing.XPen(XColor.FromName("gray"))
    Dim x As Integer = 74
    Dim y As Integer = 268
    Dim p As PdfSharp.Drawing.XPoint
    Dim xSfarsitTabel As Integer = 575
    Dim gfx As PdfSharp.Drawing.XGraphics
    Dim document As PdfDocument
    Dim page As PdfPage
    document = New PdfDocument()

    page = document.AddPage()
    page.Orientation = PdfSharp.PageOrientation.Portrait
    gfx = PdfSharp.Drawing.XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page)

    p = New PdfSharp.Drawing.XPoint(x, y)
    gfx.DrawString("TEXT THAT PRINTS", PrintFont14B, BrushBlack, p)
    p.Y += 5
    gfx.DrawLine(pen, 225, p.Y, xSfarsitTabel, p.Y)

    document.Save("C:\TempDir\test.pdf")
    document.Dispose()

    document = Nothing
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that is generating the line, preferable the entire method?

Comment: I have edited the question, and i added the code.

Comment: I don't see where `gfx` is declared.  Could it be a display issue on the machines?  If you take the generated PDF and open it on your machine, are the lines not visible?

Comment: I copied the pdf, and still no lines. I have modified the code, and declared gfx..

Comment: Are you saving the PDF to a file: `document.save` after making the changes?

Comment: I have added the lines for saving: document.save(file)

Comment: I have modified the code, so it can run directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a PDFSharp v. 1.50.5147 bug. As a workaround you can try version 1.32.3057 or older, it worked for me.